# How do interactions between multiple spline terms for different variables work in lme4? Is my approach/syntax valid?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, splines

I am currently analyzing a dataset from an experiment I ran in which I investigated the effects of different tone combinations on frog calling responses. Each stimulus presented to the frog was a combination of 2 tones of different frequencies (i.e., each individual stimulus is composed of frequency 1 and frequency 2, but each of these can take multiple different values). The 2 tones in each stimulus also differ in their intensities, and I have a large number of frequency/intensity combinations (~450). For each response of the frog to each stimulus, I recorded whether they exhibited response A or response B. I got ~23,000 responses to different stimuli from 43 frogs.

So, I built a mixed effects logistic regression with response A or B as the outcome variable. Based on previous knowledge of these frogs, I expected that responses to different frequency/intensity combinations will all be quite interdependent and context specific, so I included a 3-way interaction between tone 1 frequency, tone 2 frequency, and intensity difference between tones 1 and 2. However, when checking model assumptions with DHARMa, non-linear relationships between tone 1 frequency and the outcome variable, and tone 2 frequency and the outcome variable were evident. Modeling both of these relationships with natural splines with 3 degrees of freedom seemed to fix these issues, and all of my DHARMa plots looked great after this.

model syntax:

```
glmer(frog_response ~  ns(tone_1_frequency, df = 3) * ns(tone_1_frequency, df = 3) * intensity_difference + 
(1 | block_ID) + (1| block_ID:male_ID), family = binomial, data = data)
```

I also included several other covariates I thought would be important, and included random slopes for all variables for which the data supported them (no singular fits etc.), but I didn't include these in the above example so as to reduce visual clutter.

My questions are:

- Is it valid to include an interaction between two spline terms like this?
  I realize spline coefficients are not interpreted in the same way as regular coefficients and rather denote the weight applied to a certain basis function, so does having an interaction between these coefficients make sense in the same way? From my reading, it seems as though this makes sense mathematically, but that the biggest issue with complex spline interactions like this is that interpretation of the coeffcients is very challenging. However, I am able to get nice visualizations of this 3-way interaction via SJPlot which tell a pretty clear, compelling, and reasonable story. So the broad strokes of what is going on with these frogs is very evident and interesting from the visualization, even if the coefficients themselves may be hard to interpret from the model summary table.
- So, does this approach, and the syntax I used to execute it, seem valid?
- If not, what would you recommend?

Thanks for your time and for any information you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to include interactions between splines. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77819/which-one-to-use-splines-interaction-or-both). Interpretation is definitely a problem, but you appear to have this under control with visualization.

Questions about code are not really on topic, but since this is part of a broader statistics question: Your syntax looks fine to me.